# custom proxy configuration for firefox

Tags: python, firefox, browser, proxy

I am running a python HTTP proxy on localhost. So, I want to set that proxy for a list of websites only. Is it possible? Otherwise if I can only set proxy for http websites, that will work too. The issue is that, my script cannot handle https and other protocols.

Answer (score 0):

In the Firefox proxy Settings you can set the proxy for HTTP, SSL, FTP and socks individually.
There is also a field to add sites to exclude from going trough the proxy.

Depending on the Firefox version the proxy settings can be found either at the bottom of the general preferences page or in the preferences under advanced>network>connection settings.

Or you can create a proxy auto configuration file and add it in the Firefox proxy settings.
Create the file C:\proxy.pac with the following content:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
  if (shExpMatch(host, "(*.google.com|google.com)")){
    return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:8080";
  } else {
    return "DIRECT";
  }
}
```

Then in the proxy settings set the auto configuration url to: `file:///C:/proxy.pac`

This example uses the proxy only on google.com.